# how to use jest to mock method of react class

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock method of react class so that the unit test can run follow the mock function.

React: 16.8.6
jest: 24.8.0

Overview.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Overview extends Component{
  test1(){
    return {
      // fetch api
    } 
  }

  test2(){
    const result = this.test1();
    // do other thing
    return result 
  }
}
```

overview.test.js

```
import Overview from './index';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
describe('test Overview',()=>{
  const mockResult = {test1:'test1'};
  console.info(Overview.prototype)  // {}
  Overview.prototype.test1=jest.fn(()=>{
    return mockResult
  });
  it('func test2',()=>{
    const wrapper = mount(<Overview/>);
    const {test2} = wrapper.instance();
    expect(mockResult).toEqual(test2())
  })
})
```

Expect: run success

Actual result: run fail, because Overview.prototype cannot override or mock test1 function.

When I tried to print 'Overview.prototype', I get {}. That let me so confuse.

How to mock test1 function and why Overview cannot be overrode?

Please help me.

Comment: I tried to find something from official api. The api use jest.fn(), jest.spyon() to mock function, but those demos only mock whole function or module, not single method of class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
it('func test2',()=>{
    const wrapper = mount(<Overview/>);
    wrapper.instance().test1 = jest.fn(() => mockResult);
    expect(wrapper.instance().test2()).toEqual(mockResult);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.


`wrapper.instance().test1 = jest.fn(() => mockResult);` cannot change `Overview.prototype`, so that `expect(wrapper.instance().test2()).toEqual(mockResult);` cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reason to choose different approach than mocking internal methods and checking against internal methods:

1. it's hard and even impossible somtimes(once method under mock change state or even access variable by closure)
2. you stick to implementation details so even smallest refactoring(renaming internal method or property name in `state`) make you update tons of tests
3. it makes you even more confident in your component(say what if `test1()` stopped to call `fetch()`? but your tests with mocking it would not even know that component is broken)

Here is different approach: mock only external API and communicate only through public interface(for React component it's `props` and `render()` result you may access with Enzyme's methods like `.find()`, `.filter()`, `.text()` etc)

There are several packages that mocks global `fetch()` like [`fetch-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) but you actually may mock it on your own(don't forget to mock it with `Promise` not plain data):

```
global.fetch = jest.fn();

beforeEach(() => {
  // important for mocks to keep them fresh on each test case run
  global.fetch.mockClear(); 
});

it('renders error if fetching failed', async () => {
  global.fetch.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject({}));
  const wrapper = shallow(<Overview />);
  wrapper.find('.some-button-to-click').props().onClick();
  await Promise.resolve(); // let's wait till mocked fetch() is resolved
  expect(wrapper.find('.error').text()).toEqual('Unable to load users. Try later.');
});
```